# Dictionary init(grouping:by:), 2 levels - simplifying code

Tags: swift, dictionary, functional-programming, swift5

`Dictionary(init(grouping:by:))` works fine when I need to group array elements by some property.

What I get is:

```
{
    key1: [
        value1,
        value2,
        value3
        ],
    key2: [
        value4,
        value5,
        value6
        ]
}
```

However, I need to transform the array further, grouping every partition into smaller groups so, that the resulting data structure is having two layers:

```
{
    key1: {
        anotherKey1: [
            value1,
            ],
        anotherKey2: [
            value2,
            value3]
    },
    key1: {
        anotherKey3: [
            value4,
            ],
        anotherKey4: [
            value5,
            value6]
    },
}
```

What is the simplest way of achieving this result? Currently I have to iterate over the result of the 1st dictionary initializer call:

```
        let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: Array(source), by: {$0.key1)
        var grouped2 = [KeyType1 : [KeyType2? : [ValueType]]]()

        for pair in grouped {
            if let key = pair.key {
                grouped2[key] = Dictionary(grouping: pair.value, by: {$0.key1})
            }
        }


        print(grouped2)
```

And this gets me exactly the result I want: two-level dictionary of arrays.

**But I suspect, there is a simpler way of achieving the same result, without manually interating over every key/value pair.**

Comment: I can't test this because you haven't given us any test data to work with, but you can solve your problem using `mapValues`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by doing a `init(grouping:by:)` call, followed by a `mapValues` call, which further maps every "group" into another dictionary. And this dictionary is going to be created by `init(grouping:by:)` again, using the second grouping key.

i.e.

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: source, by: firstKey)
    .mapValues { Dictionary(grouping: $0, by: secondKey) }
```

For example, to group a bunch of numbers first by their `% 2` values, then by their `% 4` values:

```
let source = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: source, by: { $0 % 2 })
    .mapValues { Dictionary.init(grouping: $0, by: { $0 % 4 }) }
print(grouped)
```